# Error if excel file exists in the Temp folder

Tags: vb.net

Following code works good.

```
Dim xlProcess As New Process
xlProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "EXCEL.EXE"
xlProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/x /safe /readonly ""C:\Book1.xlsx"""
xlProcess.Start()
```

Following picture shows the error when I just change directory.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put a & before the System.IO.Path.GetTempPath. You also forgot to put the double quote after /readonly. It should be like this:

```
Dim xlProcess As New Process
xlProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "EXCEL.EXE"
xlProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/x /safe /readonly """ & System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & "Book1.xlsx"""
xlProcess.Start()
```